# How might I read "$\cos\left(\theta\right):\sin\left(\theta\right):1::x:y:r$"?

Tags: soft-question, polar-coordinates

In the book I'm reading, *A Course in Pure Mathematics*, the author writes the following when introducing polar coordinates in section 22:

\begin{align}\cos\left(\theta\right):\sin\left(\theta\right):1::x:y:r\end{align}
How do I read this in words correctly? I've never seen such notation before. Here is a snippet of the page in the book:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a three-way proportion. The expression

$$a:b:c::x:y:z\tag{1}$$

means that there is a constant $k$ such that $x=ka,y=kb$, and $z=kc$. Here the relationship between $1$ and $r$ means that we must take $k=r$, so that $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

Equivalently, $(1)$ says that any two of $a,b$, and $c$ have the same ratio as the corresponding two of $x,y$, and $z$.

Answer (score 4):

When literally read in words, it's "cosine theta is to sine theta is to one as x is to y is to r". The other posts explain the meaning.

Comment: +1 also. I am sorry I cannot mark two answers as being correct, although yours certainly answers my question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Can be handled like fractions
$$\left. \begin{gathered}
  \frac{{\cos (\theta )}}{x} = \frac{1}{r} \hfill \\
  \frac{{\sin (\theta )}}{y} = \frac{1}{r} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right\} \Rightarrow \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {x = r\cos (\theta )} \\ 
  {y = r\sin (\theta )} 
\end{array}$$